pandas.DataFrameを継承した子クラスオブジェクトから親クラスメソッドを呼び出した場合返り値が親クラスの型になる
下記のように pandas.DataFrameを継承して新しくNewDataFrameクラスを作成します。NewDataFrameクラスのメソッドとしてmedianを定義しています。これは新たなNewDataFrameオブジェクトを返すものです。一方、NewDataFrameオブジェクトから親クラスpandas.DataFrameのメソッド（下記ではquery）を呼び出すと返り値がpandas.DataFrameのオブジェクトとなります。ですので、さらにmedianメソッドを実行しようとしてもエラーとなります。このような子クラスから親クラスのメソッドを呼び出して返り値を子クラスのオブジェクトとすることはできないのでしょうか。
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Alpha'] = ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3 + ['C'] * 4
df['Num'] = [i for i in range(9)] + [np.nan]

# define newdataframe class
class NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        super().dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)

    def median(self, aggby):
        return type(self)(self.groupby(aggby).median())

ndf = NewDataFrame(df)
ndf_median = ndf.median(['Alpha'])
print(type(ndf_median)) # --><class '__main__.NewDataFrame'>
ndf_query = ndf.query('Alpha == "A"')
print(type(ndf_query))# --> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
ndf_query.median(['Alpha']) # --> Error


pandas.DataFrame クラスのメソッドをラップします。NewDataFrame.median() は、同名のメソッドが pandas.DataFrame クラスにあるため名前を変更しています。(grouped_median())
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import inspect

# make dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Alpha'] = ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 3 + ['C'] * 4
df['Num'] = [i for i in range(9)] + [np.nan]

# define newdataframe class
class NewDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def wrapper(self, m):
        parent = self.__class__.__bases__[0]
        def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
            f = getattr(parent, m)
            if inspect.ismethod(f):
                result = f(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)

            if isinstance(result, parent):
                result = type(self)(result)
            return result

        return wrap

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        super().dropna(how = 'any', inplace = True)

        parent = self.__class__.__bases__[0]
        for m in dir(parent):
            if not m.startswith('__'):
                try:
                    method = getattr(parent, m)
                    if callable(method) and not inspect.isclass(method):
                        setattr(self, m, self.wrapper(m))
                except:
                    pass

    def grouped_median(self, aggby):
        return self.groupby(aggby).median()

ndf = NewDataFrame(df)
ndf_median = ndf.grouped_median(['Alpha'])
print(type(ndf_median)) # --> <class '__main__.NewDataFrame'>
ndf_query = ndf.query('Alpha == "A"')
print(type(ndf_query))  # --> <class '__main__.NewDataFrame'>
print(ndf_query.grouped_median(['Alpha']))

